# Milvus vector database similarity search

Tags: milvus

Does Milvus supports partial loading of collection in memory to perform similarity search? I mean, based on the input vector, will it be able to identify and auto-load clusters of vectors which most likely are similar?

If no, is there any vectordb (like faiss, nmslib etc) which supports partial loading of indexes in memory?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for indexes like DiskANN - it holds ~10% of the vectors in memory and the rest on disk

I believe IVF Flat also holds only the centroids and then does a flat search on the vectors within the closest centroids.